# Can't compile a module in java 9 using cmd

Tags: java, module, java-9, java-module

Ok, so I'm trying to learn java 9 trough a book I bought, but when I try to compile a module trough the cmd, I get this error message. [image of the cmd compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k0lI.png)

I have been trying to understand what is happening for the last 2 days.

Comment: Yes, an argument for module-source-path is missing. You specify the switch but forgot to add the path.

Comment: Try this link: https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start - maybe a slightly different point of view will help.

Comment: Don’t post images of errors. Copying the text into the browser is easier than making a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the screenshot you posted is that `--module-source-path` requires a path, identifying where the modules' source files are, so that it can compile them. Since you haven't specified where the source files are, the compiler is complaining about it.

If the project structure is

```
modulename/src/main/java/module-info.java
modulename/src/main/java/com/whatever/Main.java
```

then the command to compile it would be (run from the parent of `project`)

`javac -d outputfolder --module-source-path "./*/src/main/java" -m modulename`

The `*` symbolizes the module's directory.

I suggest you go through the examples in your book by following the tutorial before experimenting.